Possible cycle structures for S8, and then A8.
(Bear with my long answer; I thought outlining my thinking might provide for more fruitful feedback.)
The Question:
The initial question I am asked is "Does A8 contain an element of order 26?".
My initial solution was to use Lagrange and show that since A8 is a subgroup, the order of A8 must divide 26. But I wanted to try in without Lagrange.
Rough Idea for a Proof:
I learned that the order of a permutation is the lcm() of the number of elements, so for example order of (1 2 3) is 3, order of (1 2)(1 2 3 5 9) = lcm(2, 5) = 10. So I was thinking a valid approach to the initial question would be find the possible structures of the cycles in A8 and then see if such a lcm() exists.
Finding Cycle Structures in S8 and A8:
I am not sure how to quickly find cycle structures in A8 but I know A8 consists of the even ones of S8 so I would start with that.
Additionally, I am not 100% on what "cycle structure" means but this would be my guess for the possible ones in S8.

4 2-cycles
5-cycle and a 3-cycle
6-cycle and a 2-cycle
7-cycle and a 1-cycle
1 8-cycle

So if A8 has the even ones (the even ones are the ones who have an odd number of elements) then the possible structures in A8 are:

4 2-cycles (2 transpositions would be even)
5-cycle and a 3-cycle
7-cycle and a 1-cycle

Putting it Together:
The possible lcm()'s are then: 2, 15, and 7 respectively. Hence, since non of these are a lcm of 26, no such element with order 26 exists in A8.

"the order of $A_8$ must divide $26$." You have it backwards. If a group $G$ contains an element of order $26$, then $26$ divides the order of $G$,not the other way around.

You're missing lots of possible cycle structures. For example, a permutation in $A_8$ might be a 2-cycle and two 3-cycles, like $(1\,2)(3\,4\,5)(6\,7\,8)$, or a 4-cycle (and four $1$-cycles), like $(1\,2\,3\,4)$.
But you don't need to enumerate all the possible cycle structures. Just note that all cycles have length $\leq 8$, and no collection of natural numbers $\leq 8$ has $26$ as a least common multiple, since $13$ is a prime factor of $26$.

It can't because the order of an element divides the order of the group (Lagrange), but $26\not\mid 8!.$
As a slightly different way,  there's no $13$-cycles in $S_8.$
